# Blackberry debug output

Tags: windows, linux, debugging, macos, blackberry

When a Blackberry phone is connected via USB and in debug mode, calls made to System.out.println() are visible in the log.

But is there any way to get access to "stdout" even from a program not in debug mode?  Attaching with some command line program perhaps?

Comment: Do you know about the `alt+lglg` from the home screen to show the system log? Hold down `alt` and type `lglg` from the home screen, and it will show you all the log entries from all the running applications. I use it frequently to guess which security permissions are _required_ for a program to run correctly.

Comment: no, what is lglg? That was interesting, it can be useful sometimes. Aha - lglg is not a button, but a sequence of L G L G :-)

Comment: I tried that and while cool and useful sometimes too, it's just TOO much junk in that log for me to find anything on the small BB screen.

Comment: @sarnold, head over to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674161/can-i-show-the-system-log-on-a-blackberry-phone and earn some rep. :-)  This was interesting enough it needs to be documented on SO properly.

Comment: Under `Options` you can filter it to just show a handful of event types, rather than the full list. It _is_ a lot, and a filter / search would go a long way towards improving it. :)

Comment: I worked around it by creating an over-the-network logging function.

Comment: @Ami, might as well write that as an answer and accept it. Pity there's nothing built-in, but that sounds tolerable enough. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked around the issue by creating an over-the-network logging function.

Comment: +1 I did something similar; I was quite proud of it :).  I created a local logger with a mechanism to automatically email it to our server.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the JDE installed and BB plugged in via a USB:

JavaLoader.exe -usb eventLog > theLog.txt

This is often much more convenient for accessing the logs during dev.
There's no way to programmatically get the content though.

Comment: Nice!  I like it. Is that a Windows only thing? I have a bunch of Java Loaders in my plugins directory, but only for up to OS 5.0

Comment: I think it's only windows.  The JavaLoader tool has been in the JDE since at least 4.1.  It also works on simulators.