# Can I show the system log on a Blackberry phone?

Tags: blackberry, logging

Is there a way to display the system log *from within* a Blackberry phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hold down the `alt` key while typing `LGLG` at the home screen (lowercase is fine, but upper case is easier to read `L` characters), you'll enter the system log. It's *huge*, and not easily searched, but under the Options you can find a mechanism to filter entries by type.

Answer (score 3):

Hold the alt key and press lglg.

Comment: Thanks! :)   I had no idea. Further proof that BB developers are actually caring about 3rd party developers, despite their signing frenzy. :)

Comment: If they cared about third party developers, they would make it possible for apps to access a stack trace for bug hunting purposes.